# play() function in ipython is undefined

Tags: python, audio, ipython

I know there are similar questions about playing sound in ipython but those are about playing sound files while I'm trying to create a sound on the notebook and play that. If not sure if the process for  playing sound is the same regardless sso excuse me as im new to ipython.

Code

```
samplerate = 44100 
duration = 3 
t = arange(0, duration, 1/samplerate)
x440 = 0.5*sin(2*pi*440*t)
play(x440)
```

Error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7e76222fe221> in <module>()
----> 1 play(x440)

NameError: name 'play' is not defined
```

Comment: pretty obvious error, where have you defined play?

Comment: any module you are using??

Comment: @avinashpandey i haven't imported any. I thought the function was built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, a [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError) means that name hasn't been defined anywhere. This means you haven't defined it anywhere. It also isn't a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). You can't call a function that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing an import. 
You need to import some of the audio modules to be able to play sound.
Here you can find a list of audio modules
[From the python official docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/)

Comment: whats the best way to import them?

Comment: If you want to be able to create your own audio files, like in your example. This is a great library you can use:
[Audiolab](http://cournape.github.io/audiolab/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import gym
from gym.utils.play import *
play(gym.make("Pong-v0"))
```

While you are in the game. You can use KEY "A" and "D" to control.